# Cocoa Application Template - MainMenu.xib - Main Window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, osx-snow-leopard

When you create a new application in Xcode, it automatically creates a AppDelegate and a MainMenu.xib. The latter also contains the application main window, which is linked to the AppDelegate as an IBOutlet.

What I tried to do is, use a MainWindow from a different xib-file. However, there's absolutely nothing I can do to prevent Cocoa from showing the first window it created in the first place, even if I remove the IBOutlet link and comment it out in the source file and what not...

Hope someone can explain this, as it  has been bugging me for a while now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not a window in a XIB is shown at launch is **not** controlled by an explicit code, but instead controlled by the state of the window "freeze-dried" in the XIB.

More concretely, in an inspector of an `NSWindow` in the Interface Builder, you have the option called `Visible at launch` under the heading `Behavior`.
When the Cocoa system loads a nib and encounters a window with this bit on, it just shows it on the screen. It's independent of whether you have `IBOutlet` or not. You see, it's also the Cocoa system which sets UI objects to `IBOutlet`s when it loads a nib... it can do whatever it wants.

Comment: That explains that :P Thank you so much :)